# If $\{x_n\}$ converges to x then $ \{x_n\}_{n∈\mathbb{N}}\cup \{x\}$ is a compact space

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

Prove that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $(X,d)$ that converges to a point $x$, then $ \{x_n\}_{n∈\mathbb{N}}\cup \{x\}$ is a compact space.

What I have tried has been the following:

Using the following definition of compactness:
A set X is said to be compact if, given an open cover of any X, there is a finite undercoating.

Given an open covering {$_$} of $\{_\}_{n∈\mathbb{N}}\cup \{\}$, one of them $_{_0}$ contains the limit point $$.

By definition of limit that open $_{_0}$ contains all the points of the sequence less a finite number; that finite number of points that remains outside will each be contained in an open of the coating and thus all these open together with $_{_0}$ form the finite undercoating.

But I don't know if my idea is correct or if that is enough, thank you.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: From a different perspective, is your set closed and bounded?

Comment: @Chris Leary In a general metric space a closed and bounded set might still not be compact though. It is a very nice property which holds specifically in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the usual metric that every closed and bounded set is compact.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I decided to use the compactness topological version, but I don't know if the problem can be attacked on the other hand

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the refresher. We have only that compact implies closed and bounded, not the converse. Add this to the list of things I have forgotten over the years (you can probably tell that I am not an analyst).

Comment: I have never seen the word "undercoating" in that context. Where have seen it? Usually one says "subcover".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Yes, your proof is correct.